# Redirect in AJAX in Android WebClient

Tags: javascript, java, android, ajax, hybrid-mobile-app

I found that   `window.location = '/Mobile/Main';` does not work in `WebChromeClient`. I mean it does not redirect to the page but it work fine under any PC internet browser.

I have tried

> history.pushState(null, '', '@Url.Action("Main", "Mobile")');
>   window.open('@Url.Action("Main", "Mobile")');

And it does not redirect as it works normally.

How to fix it?

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(params),
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data.success === true) {
                               // It does not redirect in Android WebClient 
                                window.location = '/Mobile/Main';
                            }
                            else { 
                                $('#msgModalBody').html(data.msg);
                                $('#msgModal').modal({
                                    keyboard: false
                                });
                            }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
                 // It does not redirect in Android WebClient
                 window.location = '/Mobile/Main';
                });
```

**Java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private WebSettings webSettings;
    private long size = 0;

    // Storage Permissions variables
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        try {
            String file_path = mCameraPhotoPath.replace("file:","");
            File file = new File(file_path);
            size = file.length();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error!", "Error while opening image file" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (data != null || mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
            Integer count = 0; //fix fby https://github.com/nnian
            ClipData images = null;
            try {
                images = data.getClipData();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error!", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            if (images == null && data != null && data.getDataString() != null) {
                count = data.getDataString().length();
            } else if (images != null) {
                count = images.getItemCount();
            }
            Uri[] results = new Uri[count];
            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (size != 0) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else if (data.getClipData() == null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(data.getDataString())};
                } else {

                    for (int i = 0; i < images.getItemCount(); i++) {
                        results[i] = images.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    }
                }
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have read or write permission
        int writePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int readPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int cameraPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

        if (writePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || cameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); //hide the title bar

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        verifyStoragePermissions(this);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.website);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

        webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        // Очищать весь кэш https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465432/android-webview-completely-clear-the-cache
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.clearFormData();
        webView.clearCache(true);

        // Javascript inabled on webview
        //webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Other webview options
        //webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        //Other webview settings
        //webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

        //webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        //webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

        //webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        // webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.setWebViewClient(new Client());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());

        //if SDK version is greater of 19 then activate hardware acceleration otherwise activate software acceleration
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }


        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();

        /* context.deleteDatabase("webview.db");
        context.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");*/

        //Load url in webview
        webView.loadUrl("http://172.16.10.3:7777");


    }

    //helper method for clearCache() , recursive
//returns number of deleted files
    static int clearCacheFolder(final File dir, final int numDays) {

        int deletedFiles = 0;
        if (dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                for (File child:dir.listFiles()) {

                    //first delete subdirectories recursively
                    if (child.isDirectory()) {
                        deletedFiles += clearCacheFolder(child, numDays);
                    }

                    //then delete the files and subdirectories in this dir
                    //only empty directories can be deleted, so subdirs have been done first
                    if (child.lastModified() < new Date().getTime() - numDays * DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
                        if (child.delete()) {
                            deletedFiles++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, String.format("Failed to clean the cache, error %s", e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
        return deletedFiles;
    }

    /*
     * Delete the files older than numDays days from the application cache
     * 0 means all files.
     */
    public static void clearCache(final Context context, final int numDays) {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("Starting cache prune, deleting files older than %d days", numDays));
        int numDeletedFiles = clearCacheFolder(context.getCacheDir(), numDays);
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("Cache pruning completed, %d files deleted", numDeletedFiles));
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        return imageFile;
    }

    public class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        // For Android 5.0+
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUploadMessage = filePath;
            Log.e("FileCooserParams => ", filePath.toString());

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }

                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[2];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(chooserIntent, "Select images"), 1);

            return true;

        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public class Client extends WebViewClient {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // If url contains mailto link then open Mail Intent
            if (url.contains("mailto:")) {
                // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                //Open links in new browser
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                // Here we can open new activity
                return true;
            }else {
                // Stay within this webview and load url
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
        //Show loader on url load
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // Then show progress  Dialog
            // in standard case YourActivity.this
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Загружается...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        // Called when all page resources loaded
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ " +
                    "document.getElementById('android-app').style.display='none';})()");

            try {
                // Close progressDialog
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried in the Client class to put "return false;" in your else statement, instead of "view.loadUrl(url); return true;" ?

Comment: @kppro Sorry, man cannot get you....Would u mind to provide some example please?

Comment: @kppro I have used  `return false;` but what is wiered it does not go to that line at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh! :)

Mega solution I just have found.

We have to simulate to post an empty form.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm" action='@Url.Action("Details","Main")'></form>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

instead of

```
window.location = '/Mobile/Main';
```

That does the trick!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459357/ajax-success-function-is-not-working-on-android-webview
I faced the same issue